# get current date in this format "May 09, 2019"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get the current time in May 09, 2019 format.

```
var d = new Date();
var delay = 500;
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var y=d.getFullYear();
var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
```

here the output shows the current time in 2019/05/09 format.how should i get "May 05, 2019" format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var d = new Date();
var months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
var month = months[d.getMonth()]
var day = d.getDate();
var y=d.getFullYear();

var today =  month +" " +day + "," +  y;

console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating (and maintain) your own array of names you can use the following:

```
d.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });

var d = new Date();
var month = d.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });
var day = d.getDate();
var y=d.getFullYear();

var today =  month +" " +day + "," +  y;    
console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
 var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
    "Nov", "Dec"
  ];

  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDate();
  var monthIndex = d.getMonth();
  var year = d.getFullYear();

  var output = monthNames[monthIndex] + ' 'day + ' ,' + year;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for

```js
function LogCurrentDate(e){
   var date = new Date();
   var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' };
   $(".output").empty().append("<p>" + date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options) + "</p>");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button onclick="LogCurrentDate(event)">Show Date</button>
</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```